# How to get a list of connected NBD devices on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, qemu

Looking at the man pages for **nbd-server** and **nbd-client** and **qemu-ndb** I don't see any way of listing what NBD devices are connected.   Is there a way of doing this?

The closest I can find by experimentation is ls **/dev/nbd** and deriving information from that.   But you have to try and mount stuff to see what it is.

Comment: Have you tried *sudo ss -ntp | grep nbd* for *TCP*  ports and *sudo ss -nup | grep nbd* for *UDP* ports?

Comment: Interesting idea.   I can also see some stuff with **lsof** | grep nbd.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using this code to attach a new `qcow` to an unused `/dev/nbd`:

```bsh
for x in /sys/class/block/nbd[0-9]{1,} ; do 
        S=$(cat $x/size)
        if [ "$S" = "0" ] ; then
            dev_name=$(basename $x)
            ${SUDO} qemu-nbd -d /dev/${dev_name} || true
            echo "connecting ${QCOW_FILE} to /dev/${dev_name}"
            ${SUDO} qemu-nbd -c /dev/${dev_name} ${QCOW_FILE} &&  IS_MOUNTED="yes" ||   ${SUDO} qemu-nbd -d /dev/${dev_name}
            [[ "${IS_MOUNTED:-no}" != "yes" ]] && continue
            break
        fi

    done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the existence of the `pid` file:

```
/sys/devices/virtual/block/nbdX/pid
```

If it is present, `nbdX` is probably mounted.
In addition, `nbd0p1` and so on subfolders appear.

You can also check the process list to see if `qemu-nbd` process is running:

```
$ ps m -C qemu-nbd
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
25982 ?        -      0:00 qemu-nbd --connect=/dev/nbd0 test.qcow2
```